# How does social-auth-app-django work with jinja2?

Tags: django, jinja2, social-auth-app-django

I'm using:

- python 3.7
- Django 2.2.13
- social-auth-app-django 3.1.0

I'm considering moving from django templates to jinja2.  Most of it makes sense, but it's not clear how the social-auth part would work.  In my settings for the DjangoTemplates backend, I've got:

```
            'social_django.context_processors.backends',
            'social_django.context_processors.login_redirect',
```

but [the django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/templates/#module-django.template.backends.django) say, "Using context processors with Jinja2 templates is discouraged."  So, are these context managers not needed with jinja?

Answer (score -1):

Never mind, I figured this out.  The answer is that I'm only converting **my** app to jinja.  Other apps I use (such as social-auth-app-django) can continue to use their existing templates.  Doh.